# powertop shows 40 wakeups/second for owfs, sensor sampling is only every 10 seconds

Tags: raspberry-pi, 1wire

I am running `owfs` (1-wire file system) and some other process samples the temperature data only every 10 seconds. Now `powertop` on that linux box shows 40 to 50 wakeup events per seconds for the `owfs` process. I assume that `owfs` goes out frequently to poll/sample the sensors which is why I see these wakeups.

Since I am very keen on energy consumption on this little machine (every little saving helps), I wonder if there is a way to reduce this wakeup frequency.

Answer (score 0):

If you start `owhttpd` and browse port :`2121` on the host you will see there is a page with timeout settings.

You can try to tweak the settings and once you are happy, put it in the `owfs.conf` file.  I have not done this but it should work.

Here are the settings/timeout options listed on my network:

```
directory
          60

ftp 
         900

ha7 
          60

network 
           1

presence    
         120

serial  
           5

server  
          10

stable  
         300

uncached    
           5

volatile    
          15

w1  
          30

# Timeouts (all in seconds) 
# cache for values that change on their own  timeout_volatile = value 
# seconds "volatile" values remain in cache 
# cache for values that change on command  timeout_stable = value 
# seconds "stable" values remain in cache 
# cache for directory lists (non-alarm)  timeout_directory = value 
# seconds "directory" values remain in cache 
# cache for 1-wire device location  timeout_presence = value 
# seconds "device presence" (which bus)  timeout_serial = value 
# seconds to wait for serial response  timeout_usb = value 
# seconds to wait for USB response  timeout_network = value 
# seconds to wait for tcp/ip response  timeout_ftp = value 
# seconds inactivity before closing ftp session
```

Comment: Hmm, well. I checked already the docs for owfs.conf on http://owfs.org/uploads/owfs.html and the only applicable timeout seems to be the `timeout_volatile`, which does not seem to affect the wakeup rate.